# H2 db cannot be found during test execution

Tags: testing, spring-boot, h2

I want to use my profile 'dev' during the test execution. But when I run tests H2 db cannot be found.
**Abstract test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyServiceStarter.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public abstract class AbstractModulIntegrationTest { ... }
```

**Properties:**

```
flyway.locations=filesystem:./database/h2
flyway.enabled=true
# hsqldb
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./db/gcrs;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.username=sa

spring.jpa.database=h2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

When I run test in the output it prints **Unable to resolve location: filesystem:./database/h2**

```
2017-03-14 18:05:24.500  INFO 7460 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.util.VersionPrinter    : Flyway 4.0.3 by Boxfuse
2017-03-14 18:05:24.500  INFO 7460 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Started.
2017-03-14 18:05:25.002  INFO 7460 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory       : Database: jdbc:h2:./db/gcrs (H2 1.4)
2017-03-14 18:05:25.018  WARN 7460 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.u.s.f.FileSystemScanner          : Unable to resolve location filesystem:./database/h2
2017-03-14 18:05:25.049  WARN 7460 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.u.s.f.FileSystemScanner          : Unable to resolve location filesystem:./database/h2
2017-03-14 18:05:25.049  WARN 7460 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.u.s.f.FileSystemScanner          : Unable to resolve location filesystem:./database/h2
2017-03-14 18:05:25.049  INFO 7460 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.006s)
2017-03-14 18:05:25.064  INFO 7460 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
2017-03-14 18:05:25.064  INFO 7460 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "PUBLIC" is up to date. No migration necessary.
2017-03-14 18:05:25.205  INFO 7460 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-14 18:05:25.220  INFO 7460 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
```

Spring boot version: 1.5.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague found the solution. The problem was in the wrong path. This solved my issue:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyServiceStarter.class, properties = {"flyway.locations=filesystem:../database/h2"})
```